# how do I access a JSON file after it has been decoded

Tags: json, flutter

I can't figure out how to access this output from JSON

```
p (2 items)
0:"message" -> "ok"
1:"results" -> List (1 item)
    key:"results"
    value:List (1 item)
    [0]:Map (4 items)
    0:"uid" -> "1"
    1:"name" -> "TallyMini"
    2:"camera" -> "2"
    3:"Version" -> "0.1.0"

enter code here
lst.add(convertDataToJson[1]['value']['name']);
```

I have tried various combinations of indexs 'result', 'list', 'value', name

Answer (score 0):

You can try like as:

```
String name= jsonData['results'][0]['name'];
```

Please let me know it's work or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using http and get a JSON object from the server. And in this case, call json.decode() method then
Flutter understands JSON as a Map . ( Map<String, dynamic> json).
So, to get the value of name field, firstly you need to access to results field.
json['results'] . It is a list, and continue accessing to the name field.
It my answer is not helpful for you, please show me more your code.